# Using the predictions of a model to train a new model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, data-science

I am trying to train a model. I only have around 8k labelled data and around 20k unlabelled data. What I was thinking is, is it OK to train and test a model using the 8k labelled data and use that model to predict the classes of the remaining 20k unlabelled data. Then, using all the data creating a new model. I am trying to do binary classification and the model works quite well on the initial labelled population.

Comment: How do you know that the 20k unlabeled data was classified correctly? If it is wrong then the whole approach will create a random oracle trained with incorrect labels. If the first 8 k values are already good enough, then the next 20k would be actually not needed? With e.g. tensorflow you can also freeze the current training data and continue later with new training data, if this is possible with your tool chain then the additional learning will be more efficient.

Comment: You're right about first 8k being good and remaining being unnecessary. This is for a job application, they sent me the notebook, so I wanted to make the most out of the data I had.

Comment: https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/File:flawed_data.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that and it's absolutely fine and this strategy is often used as well. There are just a couple of things that you need to take care of while doing so:

1. Create good stratified testing data from the labeled `18000` images. If possible use k-fold splits.
2. Now predict the other unlabelled images and get the pseudo labels.
3. Train a model on the whole dataset.
4. This is the most important step. Here you will validate your model on the k-fold splits and then evaluate if the performance of your model increases or not in comparison to the k-fold results on just the labeled data.

Keep iterating these steps till your score improves but always be careful that there is no data leak regarding the k-fold data.